# EAGLE: Delete internal layers

Tags: eaglecad, pcb-layers

I'm doing a Layout and I have some problems deleting an internal layer. As you can see in the pictures below I have 4 layers (1, 2, 15, 16). But somehow I also have a layer called Route 3 (3).

I get the error:

> Can't delete internal layers`

as soon as I try to remove the layer in the display window.

How can I remove layer 3?

[image: Display]

[image: Design Rules]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I tried a bit and found a tricky solution. I just added layer 3 to the layer setup ( [2:(1+(2*3*15)+16):15] ) and deleted it afterwards ( [2:(1+(2*15)+16):15] ).

Comment: Yeah, Eagle has all sorts of kinks in it.